# using both 837P Multiple and Single schema

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2009, biztalk-2010, edi, biztalk2006r2

I have one application which is using 837P Muliple achema.Now i have another application which needs to use 837P single schema.but how to use 837P Single schema.As both have same namespace and root node.so i cant use schema from that application also and i cant deploy my schema also.Is there any solution for this situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't believe this is possible... BT's EDI repository can only hold one schema for each document type.

Answer (score 0):

This should be per Biztalk Application.  It will match to the schema in your application; hence you should be able to have one application with multiple and another application with single - but not within the same application.